# Can we get the number of open,closed,merged pull requests for a github repository on command line (as a git shell command)?

Tags: git, shell, github, pull-request

While it is possible to get the number of open, closed, merged pull requests from Github API and other means (ex: scraping), can we get those numbers using git-shell command? (after cloning the repository). Offline retrieval will be faster and helpful! Other means of finding those numbers need an internet connection!

Comment: I don’t think so. Pull requests are not part of git.

Comment: Oh, I don't know. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

`git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head'`

You will get all pull request in your terminal

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I am able to see pull requests list from this shell command, can I also get merged, open, closed ones separately.